# Connecting to an Existing Azure Database from an MVC application using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, database-connection, azure-sql-database

So I have an app already published using Azure Mobile Services and I would now like an MVC website to look at the underlying database for this mobile service, so an administrator can modify tables etc without needing to be logged in directly to the Azure Portal.

I have copied my databases connection string into the MVC application, however every time I publish it, it creates it's own separate database in the cloud rather than looking at the existing one I have placed in the appropriate config files.

Does anyone know how to resolve this or where I can begin looking to get it to simply connect to the existing database? As the existing database was generated by my creation of the Azure Mobile Service so am unsure if this is what's causing me issues?

Cheers,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the following.

Add this to your Web.config file in your MVC application.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="Data Source=server address;Initial Catalog=Database Name;User Id=****;Password=****;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

In your Context file:

```
public ContextRepository() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<EntityName> Entities{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().ToTable("EntityTable");
    }
```

Basically because you are doing code first it probably tries to create it's own DB as it doesn't know how to map the entities to the tables.

Look at Fluent API. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591617.aspx