# How connect to an existing Azure SQL database with ASP.NET CORE MVC using Entity Framework Core with migrations?

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I have an app using Azure App Services with SQL server and SQL database that are connect to my web app on asp MVC. I've used Distributed Sql Server Cache as a table on my database and so far everything is working well and connected to each other.
Now I want to do two things:

- Add entity framework to my app (I already have the database and
  connection string)
- Run migration – after I've published my app (If    I've added for a
  example new line or new

table, now I have new version)
I'm not sure how to do those things , I've looked up on many guides and couldn't find an answer. I found a post similar to mine – but using azure functions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479358/connecting-to-an-existing-azure-database-from-an-mvc-application-using-entity-fr)
. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with the steps that I need to follow (like they did in that post) to get entity framework and the migration.

Here is my code:

Program.cs-

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

if(!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri")), new DefaultAzureCredential());

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
{
    clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(builder.Configuration["storage:blob"], preferMsi: true);
    clientBuilder.AddQueueServiceClient(builder.Configuration["storage:queue"], preferMsi: true);
});

builder.Services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db");
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "_Cache";
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
```

Home Controller:

```
namespace WebAppAzure.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly BlobServiceClient storage;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> logger;
        private readonly IDistributedCache cache;

        public HomeController(BlobServiceClient storage, ILogger<HomeController> logger,
            IDistributedCache cache)
        {
            this.storage = storage;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.cache = cache;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var containerClient = storage.GetBlobContainerClient("public");
            var blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient("image.jpeg");
            var model = blob.Uri.ToString();

            return View(model: model);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            var stringModel = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            cache.SetString("name", stringModel);
            return View(model: $"SET: {stringModel}");
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            var stringModel = cache.GetString("name");
            return View(model: $"GET: {stringModel}");
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Add entity framework to my app (I already have the database and connection string)**

Use below code for add Entity framework and upload to azure app service and run migration command to migrate database.

DBcontext file in project.

```html
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication_72783922.Entity;

namespace WebApplication_72783922
{
    public class DbConnectionEntity : DbContext
    {
        public DbConnectionEntity()
        {

        }
        //string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:dbcon").ToString();
        public DbConnectionEntity(DbContextOptions<DbConnectionEntity> options) 
            : base(options)
        {

        }
        public virtual DbSet<Users> users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<department> Departments { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=xxxx;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=adminserver72783922;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs File code.**

```html
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
     
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = "Server=xxxx;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=adminserver72783922;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "_Cache";
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

- **Run migration – after I’ve published my app**

```html
Enable Migration using this command on Package Manager Console enable-migrations
Then add-migration InitialCreate
Then create migrationadd-migration test-v1
update database update-database -verbose
```

[image]